# Why sometimes I had to parseJSON and sometimes not when doing ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 basic test applications where I do ajax requests. After calling the ajax request, for the first one, I need to **parse the ajax data.responseText** before retrieving the values. For the second one, I can **access values directly**.

Code of the first app:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("JsonAdd", "People", new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "JsonAdd_OnComplete" }))
{
...
}

function JsonAdd_OnComplete(data) {

    var json = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

    if (json.Success) {
        $("#PersonList").html(json.PartialViewHtml);
    }

    $("#addPersonModal").slideToggle();
    $("#message").html(json.Message);
}
```

As you can see, I need to parse the data.responseText first before getting values.

Here is the second app:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_NewPersonToKeepInformed", "General", new { id = "NewPersonToKeepInformed" }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Are you sure ?", HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "AddedSuccess" }))

function AddedSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.message);
}
```

For this one, I cas access values directly.

**UPDATE**

Here is my controller action method:

```
    public JsonResult JsonAdd(AddPersonViewModel AddPersonModel)
    {
        ...
        return Json(new
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "The person has been added!"
        });
    }
```

Here is the second one:

```
    public JsonResult _NewPersonToKeepInformed(NewPersonToKeepInformedViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ...
        // return newly added person in a Json object
        return Json(new { message = "Ajout effectué", firstName = viewModel.FirstName, lastName = viewModel.LastName, phone = viewModel.Phone, mail = viewModel.Mail });
    }
```

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: What is that `@using` syntax? Where is the `Ajax` object coming from?

Comment: This is from ASP.NET MVC syntax. The Ajax object is coming from there.

Comment: return Json(new
            {
                Success = true,
                Message = "The person has been added!"
            });

Comment: I think jQuery is capable of having JSON parsing on/off. Might have something to do with that.

Comment: Show us your controller action methods

Comment: @Zach I updated my question to show my controller action method

Comment: where is the second one that you are comparing it to?

Comment: @Zach, ok, I updated for the second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case you use the `OnComplete` and in the second you use `OnSuccess`. That's the difference. They correspond to jQuery's `complete` and `success` callbacks. jQuery doesn't parse the server's response based on the Content-Type header inside the `complete` callback. That's why you need to parse it manually. In the `success` callback this is done automatically. So if you want this to work for your first action replace `new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "JsonAdd_OnComplete" }` with `new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "JsonAdd_OnComplete" }`